# Can Nautilus mount NFS shares?

Tags: nautilus, nfs

I can mount server's (Ubuntu Server) NFS share just fine like:

```
sudo mount 192.168.1.120:/srv/Share1 /mnt/Share1
```

In nautilus, however, nothing works:
I've tried

```
nfs://192.168.1.120:/srv/Share1  
nfs://192.168.1.120/srv/Share1
```

I always  "Oops something went wrong, and "Don't have permissions to access the requested location."

Answer (score 4):

It can, if GVfs supports it. [GVfs](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gvfs) is what Nautilus uses for mounting things other than our usual block devices (like samba shares, MTP for Adroid phones, etc.). However, `gvfsd-nfs` won't be [packaged for Ubuntu 18.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1637988). It is available for [19.04 and above in `gvfs-backends`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=disco&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=gvfsd-nfs) (along with the other GVfs backends). If you install `gvfsd-nfs`, Nautilis will be able to mount NFS shares.